# Variables in queries in stored procedures on SQL Server - how?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am working on some pretty long and complicated procedure in T-SQL where I need to use quite a lot variables in queries.

I got stuck on something like this:

```
SELECT @TableSQL = 'SELECT ' 
                   + @columnsForInsert 
                   + '= COALESCE(@columnsForInsert 
                   + ''], ['', '''') 
                   + name 
FROM MIGRATION_DICTIONARIES.dbo.' + @TableName + '_COLUMNS '
EXEC sp_executesql @TableSQL
PRINT @columnsForInsert
```

As you can see I try to concatenate all the rows from some temporary table into a single line and then assign it to `@columnsForInsert` variable. However, when I run this string by `sp_executesql` it goes to the scope where `@columnsForInsert` is not visible.

Do you have guys any idea how to get this running?

In other words. I have something like

```
SELECT @columnsForInsert = COALESCE(@columnsForInsert + '], [', '') + name 
FROM MIGRATION_DICTIONARIES.dbo.Foobar_COLUMNS
```

This works fine in my procedure. However, in the final version Foobar will be in a variable so simple putting `@tableName` there does not work. How can I achieve this?

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2012

Comment: that syntax makes no sense...

Comment: I need to make it work on 3 databases and varying table names so I need to prepare query dynamically and this is all I found 'till now. Other queries built like that worked but I don't know how to assign result to variable. If you have better idea how to solve it - I'm open.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to capture output from `sp_executesql`

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/262499

Although I have never done it, it implies that the below syntax might work to retrieve your variable value from your `sp_executesql` (assuming all the quotes are in the right place and your syntax is correct)

```
DECLARE @columnsForInsertOUT VARCHAR(400)
DECLARE @columnsForInsert    VARCHAR(400)
DECLARE @ParmDefinition      VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @TableSQL            VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @TableName           VARCHAR(200)

SELECT @TableSQL = 'SELECT @columnsForInsertOUT = COALESCE(@columnsForInsertOUT' 
               + ''], ['', '''') 
               + name 
FROM MIGRATION_DICTIONARIES.dbo.' + @TableName + '_COLUMNS '

SET @ParmDefinition = '@columnsForInsertOUT varchar(400) OUTPUT'

EXECUTE sp_executesql
@TableSQL,
@ParmDefinition,
@columnsForInsertOUT=@columnsForInsert OUTPUT

SELECT @columnsForInsert
```